# Android Where to call changecursor?

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter

I have a custom SimpleCursorAdapter with a getView like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
    //this.changeCursor(c); tried this didn't work.
    this.c.moveToPosition(position);
    int urlCol = c.getColumnIndex("url");
    final String url = c.getString(urlCol);
    //other code stuff.
    imageDownloader.download(url, thumbnail, rowId, db,pb);
```

The imageDownloader calls an update on the DBAdapter but the c.getString(urlCol) still gives me the previous value. I tried putting changeCursor at the position above but I still got the same value. Where exactly should I be calling this? Thanks!

I actually don't want the ListVIew to redraw I just want to get the latest data into the cursor. I'm passing in my imageview and url into the ImageDownloader class to download the image, set the bitmap to the imageview and update the database. I noticed the cursor was not updated as the getView method returns me the same data.

This is my custom simplecursoradapter declaration. getview is mentioned above.

```
public class MessagesCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

private final ImageDownloader imageDownloader = new ImageDownloader();
```

ImageDownloader class

```
public void download(String url, ImageView imageView, int rowId,
        TestDbAdapter db,ProgressBar pb) {

//url can be a http:// or /mnt/sdcard/mnt/ etc etc 
//some lenghty code to check if it exists physically on the phone. else....
forceDownload(url, imageView, rowId, db,pb);

private void forceDownload(String url, ImageView imageView, int rowId,
        TestDbAdapter db,ProgressBar pb) {

    BitmapDownloaderTask task = new BitmapDownloaderTask(imageView, rowId,
            db,pb);
```

AsyncTask class in the ImageDownloader class

```
class BitmapDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    private String url;
    private int rowId;
    private TestDbAdapter db;
    private ProgressBar pb;
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;      
    public BitmapDownloaderTask(ImageView imageView, int rowId,
            TestDbAdapter db,ProgressBar pb) {
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
        this.rowId = rowId;
        this.db = db;           
        this.pb = pb;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {         
        url = params[0];
        return downloadBitmap(url);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {

        if (isCancelled()) {
            bitmap = null;
        }

        if (imageViewReference != null) {
            ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
            BitmapDownloaderTask bitmapDownloaderTask = getBitmapDownloaderTask(imageView);

            if ((this == bitmapDownloaderTask)) {
                int pos = url.lastIndexOf("/");
                String fileName = url.substring(pos, url.length());
                System.out.println(fileName);

                String extLoc = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/Test";

                File folder = new File(extLoc);
                if (!folder.exists()) {
                    folder.mkdir();
                }

                try {
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(extLoc
                            + fileName);


                    boolean result = db.updateMessageUrl(rowId, extLoc + fileName);
//should update cursor here, purpose is to change the url link to a physical location on the phone.

                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 95, out);

                    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    options.inTempStorage = new byte[24 * 1024];
                    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                    options.inSampleSize = 2;

                    Bitmap thumbnail = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(extLoc
                            + fileName, options);


                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                    addBitmapToCache(url, bitmap);

                    pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Ok if it looks weird, I'm just hiding some names.

Answer (score 0):

First do:

```
c.moveToFirst();
```

before access ANY data then do the rest you want. In your case call `c.moveToFirst()`, not in `getView()` but outside, since you'll get all the same, because getView() is called multiple times when it performs the populating. Perhaps, call it in the method where you are returning the cursor.

When you do the accessing, dont forget to move the cursor for the next data `c.moveToNext();` you MUST do this inside getView();

Comment: You don't have to call c.moveToFirst(); when using c.moveToPosition(position).

Comment: Hmmm, to elaborate further on the situation, imageDownloader.download calls an AsyncTask to perform an update in the adapter, problem is I create my cursoradapter in the ListActivity. So how do I access that cursor and call the changecursor? Or is there some other method?

Comment: Are you adding new data to the cursor? If you do, thenyou need to trigger the listview to update itself with the new data. Then u should call `cur.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Changing the data in the dbadapter, I have no access to the cursor from the imagedownloader.

Comment: Then the cursor must have the new data, so `c = new youradapter(yourclass.this.getBaseContext, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, yournewdata);` now your cursor has the new data. Then call c.notifyDataSetChanged() and then c.notifyDataSetInvalidated() which will signal that listview has redrawn with the new data.

Comment: Yes I know this works if I exit the ListActivity and come back but I'm calling the download method in the getView, so how am I gonna call setListAdapter in an ASynctask?

Comment: Call it in `postExecute()` method

Comment: This only works if the Asynctask is in the ListActivity which it currently is not, it's inside another standalone class.

Comment: Then try YOURCLASS.this.list.setListAdapter(), but why dont you just move it in this class? Make things the easy way.

Comment: I need data from the cursor to perform the downloading. Anyway I don't think you can do a static call to the list like that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a good answer that will work with the way your CursorAdapter is setup.

You should only run AsyncTask once from the ListActivity. Maybe have the AsyncTask download all images in the database which are pending download and update the database? You can use onProgressUpdate to call a method in ListActivity to do the notifyDataSetchanged().

What you want is [notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) and notifyDataSetInvalidated(). Your asyncTask onPostExecute method should return a new/updated cursor to the ListActivity then from the ListActivity call notifyDataSetchanged() and notifyDataSetInvalidated.

Edit:
 [Same question as this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013380/refresh-a-simplecursoradapter-after-performing-work-on-a-non-ui-thread)

Comment: First he has to apply he new data to the cursor with the data in the adapter, then signal the listview to repopulate.

Comment: My AsyncTask currently returns a BitMap after downloading and I set it in the ImageView, after which I update the dbAdapter, even if I return the cursor, it goes to the getView method, then how do I return this to the listactivity?

Comment: [AsyncTask onPostExecute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)) runs on the UI thread. You can call a method inside ListActivity from onPostExecute.

Comment: Does this only work if the AsyncTask is in the ListActivity itself? If it is then we have a problem. I've even shifted my methods into the custom SimpleCursorAdapter and calling changeCursor(c) and nothing happens.

Comment: Yeah, you would have to put the AsyncTask inside the ListActivity. After doing changeCursor(c) call notifyDataSetInvalidated(), that forces the listview to redraw.

Comment: I actually don't want the ListVIew to redraw I just want to get the latest data into the cursor. I'm passing in my imageview and url into the ImageDownloader class to download the image, set the bitmap to the imageview and update the database. I noticed the cursor was not updated as the getView method returns me the same data. Oh well time to look for alternatives since I can't put the asynctask in the listview.

Comment: When data is updated in the database/cursor, the listview has to redraw to show the new data. Your only choices are AsyncTask or a runnable/thread to do the image downloading. maybe post more of your code and we can try to help more.