# Issue on Changing the image in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, simplecursoradapter

I am writing an android application to list the item from database, and mark some of those item as favorite and keep update the database according to favorite.

`My Aim is`:

When I mark particular item of listView as favorite, the image of that particular list item will be changed and the corresponding column of table should be updated as favorite(yes) or not favorite(no).

It was working fine to list the item from database, change the image source according to favorite, update the database also.

`My Problem is`:

1.When I press an image of particular item, the image would be changed `once`, and corresponding database also would be changed. But, Clicking on the same image `another time`(last time clicked image) `does not change anything`(not change image and not update).

2.`By scrolling the listView keep the listview as before changing the listView`.

I refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965351/android-change-image-for-a-particular-item-in-listview), `before` I `use database`. It was working fine.

After I use Database, I changed my code as below:

```
public class EpisodeCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    public final String TAG = "EpisodeCursorAdapter";
    //private String strurl = "http://timesofindia.feedsportal.com/c/33039/f/533916/index.rss";
    public int favourite[];
    private Cursor c,temp_cursor;
    private Context context;
    AABDatabaseManager db;
    public EpisodeCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
            String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
        this.c = c;
        temp_cursor=c;
        this.context = context;
        Log.d(TAG, "Object size is:" +c.getCount());
//      favourite = new int[c.getCount()];
//      for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {
//          favourite[i] = 0;
//      }
    }

    static class EpisodeHolder {
        TextView title;
        TextView desc;
        ImageView thumbnail, favourite;
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.d(TAG,"NEw view in Cursor adapater"+"  "+cursor.getCount());
        Cursor cc=getCursor();
        Log.d(TAG,"NEw view in Cursor adapater"+"  "+cc.getCount()+ "   "+cc.getInt(0));

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.newView(context, cursor, parent);
    }
    public View getView(final int pos, View inView, ViewGroup parent) {


        Log.d(TAG,"getView view in Cursor adapater " + pos);
        View v = inView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.episode_row_view, null);
            final EpisodeHolder holder = new EpisodeHolder();
            db =  new AABDatabaseManager(context);
            holder.title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.desc = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.description);
            holder.favourite = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            holder.thumbnail = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);
            v.setTag(holder);
            Log.d(TAG, "Row tag is:" + v.getTag());
            holder.favourite.setTag(pos);



            holder.favourite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    int posi = (Integer) v.getTag();
                    //Log.d(TAG, "Cursor total count" + c.getCount() + "   position:" + holder.favourite.getTag() + "    view position:" + pos + " " + posi);
                    Log.d(TAG,"****************************** INFO REGARDING CLICKING ON FAVOURITE ************************");
                    Log.d(TAG,"Position of image clicked          : " + posi);
                    temp_cursor.moveToPosition(posi);
                    int id = temp_cursor.getInt(temp_cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
                    String markedAsFav = temp_cursor.getString(temp_cursor.getColumnIndex("favourite"));
                    Log.d(TAG, "Id of clicked item is : " + id + "             Favourite : " + markedAsFav);

                    if(markedAsFav.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {

                        Log.d(TAG, "****In favourite onClick*** Was not as favourite... Mark as favourite...");
                        holder.favourite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favourite_2);
                        db.updateRowAsFav(id, temp_cursor.getString(temp_cursor.getColumnIndex("favourite")));
                    } else if(markedAsFav.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "****In favourite onClick*** Was as favourite... Mark it as not favourite...");
                        holder.favourite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favourite_1);
                        db.updateRowAsFav(id, temp_cursor.getString(temp_cursor.getColumnIndex("favourite")));
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            ((EpisodeHolder) v.getTag()).favourite.setTag(pos);
        }
        final EpisodeHolder holder = (EpisodeHolder) v.getTag();
        this.c.moveToPosition(pos);
        String imageUrl = this.c.getString(this.c
                .getColumnIndex("table_epi_image"));
        String titleStr = this.c.getString(this.c
                .getColumnIndex("table_epi_title"));
        String descStr = this.c.getString(this.c
                .getColumnIndex("table_epi_description"));

        if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("favourite")).equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
                {
            holder.favourite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favourite_2);
                }
        else
        {
            holder.favourite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favourite_1);

        }

        holder.thumbnail.setTag(imageUrl);
        new DownloadImagesTask().execute(holder.thumbnail);

        //TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.title.setText(titleStr);

        //TextView desc = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.description);
        holder.desc.setText(descStr);
        return (v);
    }
 }
```

I know that i am missing something. But I couldn't find out what is that.

Please help me to solve this.

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: here the temporory coursor is same as when it was passed to the constructor thus the updated reference is not available to the cursor and it will go to the no/yes value which was previous not current you will have to update the cursor with new value

Comment: just load the cursor again

Comment: @droidhot could you please explain me briefly?

Comment: did you try notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: @Yume117 didn't... prefer some link

Comment: by link did you mean this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213200/android-listview-update-with-simplecursoradapter or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013380/refresh-a-simplecursoradapter-after-performing-work-on-a-non-ui-thread ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Yume117 said, I have called notifyDataSetChanged() method. I have updated my answer as below:

I have added this line `refreshCursorAdapter();` next to below codes in `onclick()`

```
if(markedAsFav.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {

                        Log.d(TAG, "****In favourite onClick*** Was not as favourite... Mark as favourite...");
                        holder.favourite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favourite_2);
                        db.updateRowAsFav(id, temp_cursor.getString(temp_cursor.getColumnIndex("favourite")));
                    } else if(markedAsFav.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "****In favourite onClick*** Was as favourite... Mark it as not favourite...");
                        holder.favourite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favourite_1);
                        db.updateRowAsFav(id, temp_cursor.getString(temp_cursor.getColumnIndex("favourite")));
                    }
```

**refreshCursorAdapter** is:

```
public void refreshCursorAdapter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.d(TAG,"Refresh adapter is called....***************");
        dbAdapter = new DBAdapter();
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            EpisodeCursorAdapter adapter;
            dbAdapter.open();
            cursor = dbAdapter.fetchLimitRowsFromEpisode(
                    Common.currentListCountForEpi, EpisodeActivity.refId);
            String[] columns = new String[] { DatabaseHelper.SUB_ID,
                    DatabaseHelper.EPI_FILEIMAGE_ID,
                    DatabaseHelper.EPI_TITLE, DatabaseHelper.EPI_DESC };

            // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
            int[] to = new int[] { R.id.title, R.id.description };
            adapter = new EpisodeCursorAdapter(
                    EpisodeActivity.context, R.layout.episode_row_view,
                    cursor, columns, to, Common.REFRESH);

            adapter.changeCursor(cursor);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            dbAdapter.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```