# pulltorefreshlistview not working when number of item is less than scrollable items in android

Tags: android, android-listview, pull-to-refresh

https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh

I have taken example from above link.. and I cant able to refresh it when number of item less than scrollable item..

Below is the code which is wriiten in my Activity Class

```
@Override
public void onRefresh() {

    System.out.println("on refresh");
    // disAll();
    new GetDataTask().execute();
    // listDisply.onRefreshComplete();
}

private class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String[]> {

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Simulates a background job.
        System.out.println("do in background");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
        // mListItems.addFirst("Added after refresh...");
        System.out.println("on post execute");
        loadData();
        scAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        // Call onRefreshComplete when the list has been refreshed.
        listDisply.onRefreshComplete();

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

code in oncreateview(I m using fragment)

```
listDisply = (PullToRefreshListView) v.findViewById(R.id.lvList);
    listDisply.setOnRefreshListener(this);
```

My code to setAdapter for list view.. and i have customize list view same as in above link(PullToRefreshListView, located in library)

```
cursor = db.getAllRecordsOfTransaction(search);
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            llNoTransaction.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity()
                    .getApplicationContext(),
                    R.layout.list_notransactions, cursor,
                    new String[] { "business_name",
                            "total_amount",
                            "status",
                            "purchase_datetime" },
                    new int[] { R.id.buissness_nm,
                            R.id.total_amt,
                            R.id.status,
                            R.id.purchase_date }, 0);
            scAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
                @Override
                public boolean setViewValue(View view,
                        Cursor cursor, int column) {
                    if (column == 4) {
                        if (cursor.getString(4)
                                .equals("1")) {
                            TextView stat = (TextView) view
                                    .findViewById(R.id.status);
                            stat.setText("Approved");
                        } else {
                            TextView stat = (TextView) view
                                    .findViewById(R.id.status);
                            stat.setText("DisApproved");
                        }

                        return true;
                    } else if (column == 5) {
                        TextView amt = (TextView) view
                                .findViewById(R.id.total_amt);
                        amt.setText("$"
                                + cursor.getString(4));
                        return true;
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            });
            System.out.println("scAdapter linearlayout visible");
            listDisply.setAdapter(scAdapter);
            listDisply.setSelection(1);
```

Comment: List view wont scroll if there is less number of items. It should have minimum items to scroll a list

Comment: I know..but i need to implement that functionality of pull to refresh list view even if number of item less than scrollable item

Comment: can you post your whole code, or at least the one where you have set the adapter for your listview.

Comment: @Shrikant  I have posted the code for setAdapter

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your above code is linked to one another, because GetDataTask has mListItems to show after refresh but in the code after edit i dont see that list (mListItems). You are getting and setting values from cursor to the list. I would suggest you to use BaseApadter for you list to bind the data, and after you added new data to it call onRefreshComplete. Also you can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5013475/1457952) here, if you want to use SimpleCursorAdapter. Hope you got my point.

Comment: I have taken refrence from that link..and I change the listview name and adapter in my code.. and i also put setadapter method from pulltorefreshlistview(from library) in comment..because i m using simplecursoradapter object instead of listadapter